# Database error while sync: OperationalError(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away'), when worker work on 24 hours

Tags: django, celery, amqp

my django work with celery, Every 24 hours of operation of a database(mysql).The first is normal, but the second is Error,and error infomation is

> OperationalError(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

my config:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'  
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'              # this was set in celery.py
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('OuranosApp.tasks', )                         # this was set in celery.py
CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'echo': True}
```

I think the need to manually close the connection with mysql. But don't know how to do.